How to write the code of bracket in this equation where the function has two different values
I am trying to type a research presentation in LATEX and I am using overleaf for it.

I want to know what is the code to type this type of bracket given below in the image.

For breaking the function( ie the content inside the bracket) I will use the kind of equation given here: How to write a function in LATEX whose value is different in [0,1/3), [1/3,1/2) ...?
Here given is the function,
$h(x)=$


ie $h(x)= f(z)$ if $z\in D\cup L$ and $h(x)=g(z), z\in D^*$
Can you please guide me?

Maybe this helps

What you're asking for is typically achieved via this: How to write conditional equations with one-sided curly brackets; also Large braces for specifying values of variables by condition (possible duplicates)

I suggest you use a cases environment.

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' environment
\begin{document}
\[
h(z)=
\begin{cases}
f(z) & \text{if $z\in D\cup L$} \\
g(z) & \text{if $z\in D^*$}
\end{cases}
\]
\end{document}

